# How to load partial view at the place where i show the form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i am new in mvc. i have just small form and i want that when i will submit the form then a partial view will render at the same place where i placed my form.

here i am giving the screen shot how our page look.
[image]

when i am rendering partial view then page looks gone and show like naked. here is the screen shot again.
[image]

i want to show the message `successfully save` at the same place where i were placed my form.

here is my full code.

### my controller code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcPractise.Controllers
{
    public class GameController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Game/

        public ActionResult Test()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(string name, string salary, string btnSubmit)
        {
            //return View("Message");
            return PartialView("MyMessage");
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

### my main view form where form data is there

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

<h2>Hello222</h2>

<div id="mydiv">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Game", FormMethod.Post, new { @Id = "Form1" }))
{
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>Name :</td>
        <td><input name="name" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>Salary :</td>
        <td><input name="salary"  type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Save"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
}
</div>
```

in my partialview i have this text only

```
<h2>Successfully Saved</h2>
```

show just guide me what i need to do without using jquery. thanks

Comment: Partial or otherwise, if you're doing a form post and returning a view which contains *only* that `h2` element, then all you're going to see is that `h2` element.  It sounds like this shouldn't be a partial view, but should instead be a normal view which uses the page layout that the rest of the views use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ViewBag or ViewData, then if you suceffully save the data you can return the same view with the message.

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(string name, string salary, string btnSubmit)
{
  if(/*check if has success*/)
     ViewBag.Success = true;
  /*do another stuff*/
  return View("View where form data is there");
}
```

Form View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

<h2>Hello222</h2>

      @if(ViewBag.Success != null && ViewBag.Success == true) //Show the message
      {
         <h2>Successfully Saved</h2>
      }

<div id="mydiv">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Game", FormMethod.Post, new { @Id = "Form1" }))
{
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>Name :</td>
        <td><input name="name" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>Salary :</td>
        <td><input name="salary"  type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Save"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
}
</div>
```

EDIT:

Using Partial View you can get the same behavior, but rendering the PartialView directly into the page, not Returning from the controller. PartialView suppose to render pieces of HTML, not the entire page, thats the main purpose of PartialView, so, using It:

PartialView Success.cshtml:

```
<h2>Successfully Saved</h2>
```

Then Render the PartialView in the Page:

```
@if(ViewBag.Success != null && ViewBag.Success == true) //Show the message
{
  Html.RenderPartial("Success");
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. i like to know what is the main use of partialview ? if i can not replace the main view with partialview then there is problem. the only hope is i need to do load partialview using jquery then i can programmatically empty the mainview and load partialview there.

Comment: partialview can share the consistent look & feel of master page? when i render partialview  from my action then i saw site wise looks does not show. partialview is only ment for loading through jquery or render in main view hard coded at coding time ? looking for insight.

Comment: Partial view suppose to load pieces of HTML. You can get the same result as I explained above. I will Update the awnsear to show you how to do this! Take a look!